# Google Business Profile APIs

Tags: google-business-profile-api, google-business, google-business-profile

Can I track suggested changes to my profile from random users?

I want to update my profile only via my application or google business dashboard.

If any suggestion will be created via random user (for example NAME change) I want to display this information in mine application. Then decline/accept this change.

Is possible to LIST of changes suggested by users?

Example:
I created profile with name 'FOOTBALL'.
Then user suggests change in google to 'BASKETBALL'.
I want to show this suggestion to profile owner. Is is possible? How I can track those changes?

Answer (score 1):

The `getGoogleUpdated` method returns an instance of a location showing the proposed changes that Google has already accepted. For pending changes, there is only a field mask right now.

Link to reference: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/getGoogleUpdated

Comment: so in location object there will be visible pending changes? Because this endpoint returns [diffMask and pendingMask] and in location description - The Google-updated version of this location. not user updated version. do you have more details?

Comment: Google updated means Google already trusted the users that provided that info and is probably serving the info publicly already. I'm afraid the API does not offer a method to get the pending updated state of a location yet, the UI might display them, but that's about it.